# Django with AWS - Correct way to syncdb and run scheema migrations using South

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, database-migration, django-south

In development when I was running django on a local server, I first added South in my installed apps and then did

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

After that, whenever I made a change to the database, I'd do

```
python manage.py scheemamigration
python manage.py migrate appName
```

I now am using AWS elastic beanstalk and do

```
git add .
git commit "change made"
git aws.push
```

to update the aws server. However, I cannot run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

because it says

```
Unknown command 'syncdb'
```

so I cannot syncdb and do scheemamigrations. What is the best way for me syncdb and do scheema migrations using South now that I am using AWS servers.

Comment: I'm guessing that `scheemamigration` is a typo and have you read this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a container command, heres a snippet from the aws docs...

> On your local computer, update your configuration file (e.g., myapp.config) in the > .ebextensions directory.

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html (Step 6, point number 2) Sorry no anchors in aws docs..

EDIT: Added in migrate flag to syncdb, and changed aws doc reference to a more pertinent one

Comment: As of Django 1.7 you can replace `django-admin.py syncdb --migrate --noinput` with `django-admin.py migrate --noinput` as syncdb has been deprecated.